# method returns null but has data inside

Tags: php, laravel

I like to get the data for this object but it returns nulll even thou it has data in the object.

This is how I call the data

```
@dump($obj->exit_type())
```

and this is the object im calling from

```
  #padding: 0.0
  #activeGroup: "Did not start / exited"
  #regions: array:1 [▶]
  #sm_count: array:1 [▶]
  #footer: "Total user: 145 Exited Prior: 101"
  #title_h: 4
  #subtitle_h: 4
  #reason_h: 4
  #exit_type: "Exited"
```

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just figure out that this will solve the problem by removing parenthesis

```
@dump($obj->exit_type)
```